# Mysteries IFS behavior

Tags: arrays, bash, macos-mojave, ifs

here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915925/4673197 I learned I can split a string into array by setting IFS.

here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429887 I learned I can join a array by IFS delimiter.

But in my test below:

```sh
0:~ $ a=(1 2 3)
0:~ $ echo "${a[*]}"
1 2 3
0:~ $ IFS=. echo "${a[*]}" # IFS=. not work
1 2 3
0:~ $ (IFS=.; echo "${a[*]}") # this works
1.2.3
0:~ $ echo $IFS # the original IFS is not change

0:~ $ v=1.2.3
0:~ $ IFS=. b=($v) # change string to array
0:~ $ echo ${b[*]}
1 2 3
0:~ $ echo "${b[*]}" # the array join by `.`!
1.2.3
0:~ $ echo ${b}
1
0:~ $ (IFS=,; echo "${b[*]}") # this still work
1,2,3
0:~ $ IFS=, echo "${b[*]}" # this not work, b array still join by .
1.2.3
0:~ $ c=(1 2 3)
0:~ $ echo "${c[*]}" # a new array join by '.' !
1.2.3
0:~ $ IFS=, echo "${c[*]}" # IFS=, not work, still join by '.'
1.2.3
0:~ $ (IFS=,; echo "${c[*]}") # this works
1,2,3
0:~ $ echo $IFS # original IFS is space

0:~ $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

from the above, I have the following guessing/questions:

1. `IFS=. echo "${a[*]}"` this change the echo environment, but not change the quoting expanding environment, so it's not work?
2. if 1 is true, why `IFS=. b=($v)` successful create the array?
3. why `echo "${c[*]}"` joined by .? the IFS should be default whitespace.

Comment: IFS=,  echo "${a[*]}"  is being interrupted by the shell as one command. And, that's why it isn't working. Break it into two commands: first, `IFS=.` and then an echo, and it will work.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html plus `a=b cmd` sets and exports a only during cmd, but `a=b c=d` sets a and c persistently. Note `echo $IFS` is always empty even when IFS is set, because the expansion of $IFS is 'split' using the same chars leaving no chars to echo; use `echo "$IFS"` or better `printf '%s\n' "$IFS"` or maybe `declare -p IFS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `IFS` setting when you do `IFS=. b=($v)` two shell assignments take place in the context of the *current* shell. The modification to `IFS` to `.` will make all subsequent array expansions of type `"${arr[*]}"` to make use of this new value. Note the double quotes here, same array expansion without the quotes won't use `IFS` i.e. `${arr[*]}`

So to answer your questions

> `IFS=. echo "${a[*]}"` this change the echo environment, but not change the quoting expanding environment, so it's not work?

You are wrong, though you are passing `IFS` to  the environment that `echo` receives. However, `echo` doesn't do anything with its environment list. The result happens because you've earlier set the value of `IFS` to `.`

> if 1 is true, why `IFS=. b=($v)` successful create the array?

This command runs as if you were executing the two commands separately. Modify the `IFS` to `.` and expand the result of unquoted string `v` into the array which undergoes word-splitting with the value of `IFS`. Since you've defined it to be `.` previously, the string is split into individual components and stored into the array.

> why `echo "${c[*]}"` joined by .? the IFS should be default whitespace.

It is already explained in the first answer. You've modified in the current shell to use `IFS` to be `.` and subsequent array expansions will take these for joining strings. If you start a new shell and run the same expansion it won't work.

---

Just to clarify one more point on when passing a variable to the local environment of the command will work. If instead of

```
var=val echo "$var"
```

if you had written

```
var=val sh -c 'echo "$var"'
```

you see the value of `var` written, because in this case, you are passing the value of `var` in the environment, the `sh` shell is run. But unlike `echo`, `sh` reads from the environment and sees the value of `var` and uses it for variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't noticed IFS=. b=($v) set two variable instead of working as a temp environment